# ng-view in Angular goes blank

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-view

I have an ng-view and a route setup for /, /second, /third and /fourth. On fourth, I have an "edit" button on each entry of a list that is tied to an ng-click function to change the input of text on that page and as it does that, to console log what it changes it to (pulling from an API).

When I click "edit", it console logs the data from the API, console logs the new text assigned to the variable shown in the text field, then immediately 'empties' ng-view. That is to say, it doesn't show any view at all. The URL is changed to localhost:4000/#.

Now, if I go to #/fourth, change the URL to just localhost:4000/#, THEN click edit, it works as expected.

It's in EJS here, but it does the same when it's in standard HTML and not rendered. I've narrowed it down to being some Angular specific issue.

A video of this happening: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c6YeQNyo7P4&feature=youtu.be

Any ideas why?

```
Plunker Update: http://plnkr.co/edit/aIpxBWee8DJX0vgxm3LQ?p=preview
```

Comment: What is the console output for that? I see you that all the code is inside an `<a>` tag (the "edit" buttons code) and it seems that it is redirecting to "#" because the js breaks.

Comment: create a demo in [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue) instead of a whole bunch of pastebin links

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/aIpxBWee8DJX0vgxm3LQ?p=preview

Comment: I tried your remove function, that one isn't working neither. Are you able to print out the id in the console?

Comment: hiding the plunker link in code blocks to avoid the requirement of providing code in the question isn't appropriate.

Comment: The remove isn't really made yet. Trying to get the edit to work first, to populate the field. 

If you pop open the console in plunker, you can see it grabs the ID. It throws an error as well, but I imagine that's a plunker error that wouldn't be there if it was in my code - as there are no errors in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `#` from the anchor on you realestateResults.html. You are using hashbang mode and it 'empties' the view cause it is an invalid URI for hashbang mode. Try to set .otherwise on your route configuration to avoid these balnk views.